# Azure Ad CORS How call web api url

Tags: javascript, api, cors, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

i want to know how to call another api like custom using js and msal library. 
I have project where can call graph api and get data about my profile, by i wondering how to change this to get data from my custom api which is placed (registered) on azure ad.

My tries generates CORS errors.

I can log in to my JS project and i cant call from this project another api except GraphApi ...

For example:
AppFirst (jsproject - localhost:3000) where i log in and get access token   -------->  (call to my api localhost:44321 ... ) makes error CORS

My code:

```
 function callApi(endpoint, token, callback) {

  endpoint = "https://common.onmicrosoft.com/api://myApiClientId";
  const headers = new Headers();
  const bearer = `Bearer ${token}`;

  headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

  const options = {
      method: "get",
      headers: headers
  };

  fetch(endpoint, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => callback(response, endpoint))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Can anybody tell me how make this call? Which address is correct to invoke other api?

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common CORS issue.

JavaScript can't normally access resources on other origins(This will cause [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) error). "Other origins" means the URL being accessed differs from the location that the JavaScript is running from, by having

- a different scheme (HTTP or HTTPS)
- a different domain
- a different port

**Solution:**

You need to make changes on the API side.

[A Guide to Solving Those Mystifying CORS Issues](https://blog.container-solutions.com/a-guide-to-solving-those-mystifying-cors-issues)